# Using "Premium (Thank-you gifts)" to enroll in membership

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, premiums

Is it possible to set up a "Premium (Thank-you gift)" option to sign a donor up for a specific membership level?

I can build a membership sign-up page, and I can put "premiums" on it. The instructions in the Manage Premiums page (`/civicrm/admin/contribute/managePremiums?reset=1`) say:

> Premiums may be tangible items (i.e. a coffee mug or t-shirt), or they may be a membership or subscription with a pre-determined duration.

However, it appears that there is no built-in way to have a "premium" be an actual membership.

Our model is the [current EFF donation page](https://supporters.eff.org/donate/join-eff-4), although in our case all donors will become members, and there are certain member levels that a donor can choose for special access on our website.